# Who was the person Deadpool was sharing his "bucket list" with?

Tags: marvel, character-identification, x-men-cinematic-universe, deadpool, deadpool-2016

In the *Deadpool* movie, in the scenes where Wade is going through his "treatment" there is one "patient" that has bit more screen time than others - he and Wade lay next to each other and they have a brief conversation about "things they'd want to do before they die". Later on we can see that guy about to be buried in the burning building nodding at impaled Deadpool and (if I I've noticed it right) he is later in the container with the slave collar, being handled by Angel Dust.

I believe that person was played by [Hugh Scott](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm1807687/?ref_=ttfc_fc_cl_t19), IMDB names his character as "David Cunningham". Is there any more info about that person?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quick search on Google reveals this link:
http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/David_Cunningham_(Earth-TRN414), 
which includes the following in the Trivia section.

> The original screenplay reveals Cunningham to be a version of the
>   character Worm from the comics.

http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Worm_(Hospice)_(Earth-616)

> In due course, Wilson formed a romantic relationship with the cosmic
>   entity Death, who regarded him as a kindred spirit. Wilson started
>   trying to kill himself, to join Death - going so far as to start
>   taunting Ajax by saying his real name (Francis) over and over, which
>   earned him the respect of his fellow Hospice patients. Then Ajax,
>   angered by Wilson’s taunts, **lobotomized Worm, the closest thing Wilson
>   had to a friend**. At Death’s prompting, Wilson killed Worm to end his
>   suffering[1].